# Disable TFS support for a Visual Studio 2010 project/solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I inherited a project at my new company that used to connect to a TFS server.  Now I only have the zip of the source/solution which I have dumped into my Kiln (mercurial) repo.

The issue I am having is every time I open the solution I see this prompt

"Please provide credentials to connect to team foundation server"

[image: Popup when opening solution]

If I hit cancel I see this...

[image]

Any ideas as to how to avoid this every time I open the solution?

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the binding to TFS from the inside your projects.
In Visual studio, with the projects loaded, open the file menu->source control->change source control->Unbind for all the projects.
This will remove a section of xml from your .csproj (or whatever type).
Save your projects and  you should be free of TFS.